# Find the bar of specific time

Tags: datetime, time, timezone, pine-script, minute

I want to buy when the price firstly crossover 10:15 high level. Or crossunder 10:15 low level I will sell. How should  mention bar for 10:15

Regards

Comment: Please be more clear with the question

Comment: Please share the code you already have.